# Android: Can I pass an array of Parcelable objects? Do I need to create a wrapper object?

Tags: android, arrays, parcelable

I have created a Parcelable Object called Task shown below

```
public final class Task implements Parcelable {
    // Lots of code, including parceling a single task
}
```

I have already written all the Parcelable code for single Tasks. But now I'm working on a new activity that requires an array of Tasks. On the one hand, I could create a TaskList

```
public class TaskList implements Parcelable { 
     List<Task> taskList;
     // other stuff
}
```

but that means I would have to create a new object and rewrite a lot of Parcelable logic (even if it's almost identical). Instead it would be really nice if I could somehow just pass an array of Tasks. But the only function I see is this one.

```
public static final Parcelable.Creator<Task> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Task>() {
        public Task createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Task(in);
        }

        // This one......
        public Task[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Task[size];
        }
        // This one......
    };
```

And I'm not really sure how Parceable would use this function to handle an array of Tasks. How can I pass an array of Tasks instead of creating a TaskList?

Comment: first there is a plugin to generate parcelable code for your object, it will save your time, second all you need to do to pass parcelable array is to add it to intent by (intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(TASK_LIST,taskList);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do something like this to write an array list into `Parcelable`:

```
public class Task implements Parcelable {
     List<Task> taskList;

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
         dest.writeValue(taskList);
         ...
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private Task(Parcel in) {
        taskList = (List<Task>) in.readValue(List.class.getClassLoader());
        ...
    }
}
```

It 100% works for me.

Answer (score 4):

first there is a plugin to generate parcelable code for your object, it will save your time, second all you need to do to pass parcelable array is to add it to intent by:

```
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(TASK_LIST,taskList);
```

you can find the plugin as explained in this screen shot
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Suppose, you want to pass list from Activity A to B.

In Activity A :

```
intent.putParcelableArrayList("task_list", actualListObject);
```

In Activity B get data  :

```
ArrayList<Task> receivedList = (Task) getIntent().getParcelableArrayList("task_list");
```